# Is this the best notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, solution-verification

I am working with two types of conjugate numbers:

1. $p + q$ in which $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $q \in \mathbb{R}$
2. $p + q$ in which $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $q \in i\mathbb{R}$

I would like to define a set which contains both types of numbers. But I would like to stress their conjugate forms. Is the following enough to describe it? Also, is this the best notation available?

$R = \{ p \pm q | p \in \mathbb{Q} \wedge ( q \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \vee q \in i \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}  )  \}$

Thanks

Comment: What does "conjugate" mean here?

Comment: Examples: $2 \pm i$, $2 \pm \sqrt{3}$. By "conjugate" I mean these kind of numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your set is
$
(\mathbb Q + \mathbb R) \cup (\mathbb Q + i\mathbb R) =
\mathbb R \cup (\mathbb Q + i\mathbb R) =
\{ z \in \mathbb C : \operatorname{Im}(z)=0 \text{ or } \operatorname{Re}(z) \in \mathbb Q \}
$.

Choose the expression that makes your intention clear to the reader. I guess it is the first one.

Comment: Sorry to bother. Maybe the last condition should have $\Rightarrow$ instead of 'or'?

Comment: Actually, $\Leftarrow$, not $\Rightarrow$...

Comment: I'm getting confused... maybe $\mathrm{Im}(z) \ne 0 \Rightarrow \mathrm{Re}(z) \in \mathbf{Q}$? [Goes to write down a truth table :) ]

Comment: @pglpm - $\text{Im}(z)≠0 ⇒ \text{Re}(z)∈\mathbb{Q}$ is equivalent to $\text{Im}(z)=0 \text{ or } \text{Re}(z)∈\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You're completely right!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, could I rewrite the first as $(\mathbb{Q} \pm \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}) \cup (\mathbb{Q} \pm i \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0})$ to stress even more the conjugates? By the way, is my notation correct, though it's clearly not the best?

Comment: @Mr.N, $\pm \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ is a convoluted way of writing $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Ihf yes you're right. I also mentined before it must be a conjugate. Thanks again!